# How to fix tabs Automatically in angular Material

Tags: css, angular-material, angular6

How to fix [tabs] Automatically. When page scrolls to top or bottom when switching between other tabs I want the tabs should be in same place.

My Code is something like this (I can't share my actual code):

```
<div class="top-nav" style="height:180px;">
  content goes here
</div>
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[image: You can find my question in this image]

Comment: Why it is not possible with `position:fixed` ?

Comment: I am using position fixed only in relative is working fine and I want to fix it in one change .